# Find and input byt its class and value with JQUERY

Tags: jquery

I have this input:

```
<input type="hidden" class="code" value="22015054">
```

And I want to find it. This is my selector:

```
var inputv =  $('input.code input[value=22015054]');
```

In the console I have this:

```
console.log(inputv.html());

"null"
```

But it does not work, how can I solve this??

Please Help.

Comment: Does it say anything in the console?

Comment: Isn't [this](http://jsfiddle.net/7x42z3sf/) enough?

Comment: No because I have multiple inputs with the code class

Comment: @crush it works. Thanks!

Comment: @juanpscotto Np. I added as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current selector is targeting an `input` element that is a ***child*** of an `input.code` element.

What it appears you actually want is to select an input element with class code and value of 22015054.

To do that, you'd write the following for your selector: `'input.code[value=22015054]'`

Here is an example that outputs the HTML for the element properly matched `input` element into a div.

```js
$('#output').text($('input.code[value=22015054]')[0].outerHTML);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" class="code" value="22015054">
<div id="output"></div>
```

So, your code would become:

```
var inputv =  $('input.code[value=22015054]');
console.log(inputv);
```

Comment: what other attributes can be added into the [] brackets?? only value?

Comment: @juanpscotto Anything really. Those brackets are for selecting attributes. If you need to match multiple attributes, I think it would be something like this: `input.code[value=22015054][type=hidden]` for example.